# Angular 2, dynamic forms; updateValue() do not update checkbox form control

Tags: forms, checkbox, dynamic, angular

I'm building a angular 2 (2.0.0-rc.4) application with the new form API (2.0.2) and i've got a problem when i'm trying to update checkbox form controls with updateValue().

**This is what i've done:**

I've built a dynamic form with the new form API (based on the section in the cookbook: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html). I've extended the form class to also handle checkboxes:

```
export class FormControlCheckbox extends FormBase <string> {
  controlType: string;
  options: { key: string, value: string, checked: boolean } [] = [];
  checked: boolean = false;

  constructor(options: {} = {}) {
    super( options );

    this.controlType = "checkbox";
    this.options = options['options'] || [];
    this.checked = this.options[0].checked;
  }
}
```

This is what it looks like when it's created:

```
new FormControlCheckbox({
    type: "checkbox",
    label: 'A label',
    name: "a-name",
    value: "",
    description: "a description",
    options: [
      {
        label: 'A label',
        name: "a-name",
        checked: false
      }
    ],
  })
```

When the application are loaded the form controls are created and grouped together, everything works fine and the form get submitted as intended. I only had to do a workaround to make the checkbox update on change and the markup are as followed:

```
<input [formControlName]="control.key" [(ngModel)]="control.checked" [id]="control.key" [type]="control.controlType" [attr.checked]="control.checked ? true : null" [value] = "control.checked" (change)="control.checked = $event.target.checked">
```

I've also tried this markup (it also works fine):

```
<input [formControlName]="control.key" [(ngModel)]="control.checked" [id]="control.key" [type]="control.controlType" [attr.checked]="control.checked ? true : null" [value] = "control.checked" (change)="control.checked = check.checked" #check>
```

**This is where my problem occurs**

I'm adding a feature that updates the control values when the form just have been loaded (the user should be able to revisit the page and update previous values). The code below update all the control values.

```
for (var key in new_values) {
  //the form control keys are the same as the key in the list of new_values
  this.form.controls[key].updateValue(new_values[key]); //works for text, select and option
  this.form.controls[key].updateValueAndValidity(); //not sure if needed?
  this.form.controls[key].markAsDirty();
}
```

Text, option and select inputs gets updated but the checkboxes are unchanged. No errors or warnings. I've searched a lot for similar problems but have not found a similar problem or a solution.

Am I missing something obvious? Or have somebody had the same problem and want to share their solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by changing the values before creating the control-groups (before this it's possible to change the values (ex. x.value). It solved my problem but do not solve the fact that dynamically changes to checkbox form controls are not reflected in the DOM element.